# Which is the method used to calculate your chances to win?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

In Mortal Kombat X's online mode (ranked match), you can see your percent chance of winning the battle before the match starts. How is this percentage calculated?

Answer (score 1):

it's calculated using a method [the Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) which calculates skill based on who you fight.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: icebat has a point. @Will309 do you have a reference that this methodology is used in MK X? I think your answer is probably the right one, but more evidence that it is used in the referred game is needed.

Comment: @FabioSilva if you google "does mortal kombat x use Elo rating system" many will answer the same thing for sources i coudnt find any from developers or the dev company